# Class not found if throw a different exception name

Tags: php, try-catch

I get a

> Fatal error: Class 'AException' not found in

when I throw an exception with a different name than **'Exception':**

```
try
{
  if ( something ) throw new AException('Error');
}
catch (AException $e)
{
  $e->getMessage();
}
```

But if I change `AException` with `Exception` it works.
Any help please?

Comment: Obvious solution: include the file where AException is defined?

Comment: To use customized exceptions, you need to create a class which extends Exception class of PHP and then include this file in program.

Comment: @PetruLebada The file that contains your custom exception class.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh so if i want to use multiple catch blocks i need to create a class for each block and inherit the Exception for every one of them?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

Comment: @PetruLebada I didn't mean that. Why you are using AException class as it is not defined anywhere in PHP.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh , it may sound ridiculous , but i thought that whatever the catch name would be , it would work , something like a built in dynamic   ... eh , doesn't matter , i should have read it carefully first , thanks a lot

Comment: @Bert , please , post an answer with your solution so i can accept it,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class for every custom exception.

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php